# Is it well known that for $n \ge 11$, between $n$ and $2n$, there are at least two primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

[Sylvester and Schur Theorem](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1934-01.pdf) says that for $x > n$, there is always at least one integer with a prime factor $> n$.

[Bertrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate) shows there is at least one and provides a method for determining a minimum number that increases as $n$ increases.

Bertrand's Postulate's proof depends on calculus to show that a function is increasing.

If my logic is sound, I have found a very elementary argument that relies on nothing more advanced than the [Arithmetic Mean/Geometric Mean](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT725/AMGM/SSMA.Bnghm.html) and argues that this is true for $n\ge 11$ (if I did my analysis correctly).

If this is already well known, could someone post a citation?  If this is easily shown to be incorrect, could you provide the reasoning or counter example.

I was able to find this [very interesting paper](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~tijdeman/shoretij.pdf) by Shorey and Tijdeman.  (It takes me a long time to digest these papers so I apologize if the answer to my question is obvious from reading this paper.)

Is there any other such paper that would be interesting?  I am trying to see how my method compares to what is well known.

Comment: If an integer $x$ is between $n$ and $2n$, and it has a prime factor larger than $n$, then $x$ is prime.

Comment: Thanks.  I updated my question.

Comment: http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram24.pdf check the result at the bottom of the 2nd page.

Comment: That's right.  Ramanujan showed this!  Thanks.  I am using a different method than he did.  I had read through Ramanujan's paper a few years ago.  A classic paper!  :-)

Comment: How long is your proof? Can you not post it?

Comment: @daniel, unfortunately, since posting this question, I found an error in my reasoning.  I am not sure if it is a fatal error or not.  If I can save the argument, I am very glad to post it.

Comment: @daniel, in working through the argument, I came up with a ridiculous conclusion which suggests that my argument must be invalid.  The fix I made led to an argument that there must be a prime between $x^2$ and $x^2+x$ for $x > 100$.  If you are interested, I have posted the argument as a question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2204852/48606)